# trying to wait on an expected element to disappear, cannot catch this error

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I have the following helper function in my protractor jasmine tests

```
this.waitForExpectedElementToBeInvisible = function (expectedElement, timeout) {

    if (timeout === undefined) {
        timeout = 3000;
    }

    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    return browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(expectedElement), timeout).then(function (element) {
        return element;
    });
};
```

All is well most of the time, but once in a while.. the element has already come and gone.  and I get an error like this :

```
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector(".my-class")
```

trouble is, this is breaking the testcase.  I tried wrapping this in a try catch to no avail..

```
try {
      return this.waitForExpectedElementToBeInvisible(expectedElement, timeout);
} catch(err){
    throw err + " " + expectedElementCSS;
}
```

I think since this is a promised based thing... I'm never going to catch the error.. How do I catch promises and their errors ??

Comment: I don't know their API but if it's promise based it should be something like: return browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(expectedElement), timeout).catch(...). Or return browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(expectedElement), timeout).then(success, failCallback)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `try`/`catch` you added will only handle exceptions at the time the promise is created.  You want to handle exceptions when the promise is being resolved (or in its resolvers).  As @sirrocco notes, most promise APIs (including Protractor's, based on Webdriver) allow for `catch` handlers in addition to `then` handlers, for handling exceptions during resolution.

```
return browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(expectedElement), timeout)
   .then(function (element) {
       return element;
   })
   .catch(function (err) {
       // check if the error is a NoSuchElementError and ignore it if so
       // otherwise re-throw it
       if (err.name === 'NoSuchElementError') { // There may be a better way to do this ...
          return null;
       }
       throw err;
   });
```

You generally don't want to use the `.then(successCB, failCB)` method since errors in the `successCB` will not get passed to `failCB` (they will get passed to a dependent `.catch`).

Comment: i got it to work without the .catch , simply adding a `,` after the first `function (element) {} , function(err)...`  is this style undesirable ?

Comment: The "two-function" `then` style is slightly different should work fine.  The difference is if any exceptions or errors occur during the `then` callback (they won't get passed to your error handler function).  Probably fine in this case.I find the `.catch()` a bit easier to read (a second anonymous function isn't that self-documenting), too.

Comment: im getting an `undefined is not a function` when trying to utilize the `.catch` .. perhaps my protractor is out of date?